# How to fix JAXB error in parsing an xml in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have some xml code in a string variable that I want to pass to my `JAXB` in order to parse it into a java object. However, when I run my code it doesn't seem to grab anything. It passes back an error with `ClassNotFoundException`. I am not sure if it is because I setup the names in the class wrong or I just forgot I certain type of annotation in the class. I tried changing some of the names but I still receive the same error.

**Error:**

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:278)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:421)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662)
    at com.example.taddmsdk.Runner.meToo(Runner.java:18)
    at com.example.taddmsdk.TaddmsdkApplication.run(TaddmsdkApplication.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.example.taddmsdk.TaddmsdkApplication.main(TaddmsdkApplication.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:122)
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:155)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:276)
    ... 11 more
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results
        xmlns="info"
        xmlns:coll="info"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="info">

    <IIsWebServiceImpl array="1"
        guid="063D0DD72D5F3A46B118D7A963306361" xsi:type="coll:com.platform.model.topology.app.web.klm.KLMWebService">
        <modules array="1" guid="FBVRKJNR75858NND2UJ3J2IC9C9R" xsi:type="coll:com.collation.platform.model.topology.app.web.klm.KLMModule">
            <fileName>D:\pubKSRF</fileName>
            <isPlaceholder>false</isPlaceholder>
            <displayName/>
            <hierarchyDomain>app.web.klm</hierarchyDomain>
            <hierarchyType>KLMModule</hierarchyType>
        </modules>
        <modules array="2" guid="IJECI89585U5FJIDNVU3FI2NF" xsi:type="coll:com.platform.model.topology.app.web.klm.KLMModule">
            <fileName>d:\SRFdata</fileName>
            <isPlaceholder>false</isPlaceholder>
            <displayName/>
            <hierarchyDomain>app.web.klm</hierarchyDomain>
            <hierarchyType>KLMModule</hierarchyType>
        </modules>
        <modules array="3" guid="VNJFVFV8238DNCNCJ3J4JNDIEJC875" xsi:type="coll:com.platform.model.topology.app.web.klm.KLMModule">
            <fileName>D:\srfData</fileName>
            <isPlaceholder>false</isPlaceholder>
            <displayName/>
            <hierarchyDomain>app.web.klm</hierarchyDomain>
            <hierarchyType>KLMModule</hierarchyType>
        </modules>
        <isPlaceholder>false</isPlaceholder>
        <displayName/>
        <hierarchyDomain>app.web.klm</hierarchyDomain>
        <hierarchyType>KLMWebService</hierarchyType>
    </IIsWebServiceImpl>
</results>
```

**Java Class:**

```
package com.example.xmlClass;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class KLMWebServiceImpl {
     ArrayList <Object> modules = new ArrayList <Object> ();
     private String isPlaceholder;
     private String hierarchyType;
     private String hierarchyDomain;
     private String displayName;
     private String array;
     private String guid;
     private String xsiType;


     //Getters
    public ArrayList<Object> getModules() {
        return modules;
    }
    public String getIsPlaceholder() {
        return isPlaceholder;
    }

    public String getHierarchyType() {
        return hierarchyType;
    }
    public String getHierarchyDomain() {
        return hierarchyDomain;
    }
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public String getArray() {
        return array;
    }

    public String getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }
    public String getXsiType() {
        return xsiType;
    }





    //Setters
    @XmlElement
    public void setArray(String array) {
        this.array = array;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setHierarchyDomain(String hierarchyDomain) {
        this.hierarchyDomain = hierarchyDomain;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setGuid(String guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setXsiType(String xsiType) {
        this.xsiType = xsiType;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public void setModules(ArrayList<Object> modules) {
        this.modules = modules;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setIsPlaceholder(String isPlaceholder) {
        this.isPlaceholder = isPlaceholder;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setHierarchyType(String hierarchyType) {
        this.hierarchyType = hierarchyType;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }



    }
```

** Java JAXB:**

```
public void xmlObjVal(String xml) {

         try {

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(KLMWebServiceImpl.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            KLMWebServiceImpl customer = (KLMWebServiceImpl) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
            System.out.println(customer);

          } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

        }
```

Comment: Do you use Java 9+?

Comment: @dan1st I am using Java 8